# PyQGIS: Spatial Join: How do I correctly pass the parameters for qgis:joinbylocationsummary?

Tags: pyqgis, spatial-join

```
def joinSum(layer, j):
    output = 'memory:sel_{}'.format('test')
    params = {'INPUT': layer, 
                'JOIN':j,
                "JOIN_FIELDS": ['area_gst'],
                "SUMMARIES": ['count','sum'],
                'PREDICATE' : [0],
                "DISCARD_NONMATCHING":True,
                'OUTPUT': output} 
    result = processing.run('qgis:joinbylocationsummary', params)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
    return result['OUTPUT']
```

I figured the parameters for SUMMARIES have to be passed as list containing strings that match [these in the source code lines 150-152](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SpatialJoinSummary.py) however i get a "Incorrect parameter value for SUMMARIES" error. So how do I correctly pass those parameters ?

**EDIT:** Apparantly the parameters have to be passed on as integers but how do I know which number represents which summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never mind; It's right [here in the source code line 91](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SpatialJoinSummary.py):

```
self.statistics = [
    ('count', self.tr('count')),
    ('unique', self.tr('unique')),
    ('min', self.tr('min')),
    ('max', self.tr('max')),
    ('range', self.tr('range')),
    ('sum', self.tr('sum')),
    ('mean', self.tr('mean')),
    ('median', self.tr('median')),
    ('stddev', self.tr('stddev')),
    ('minority', self.tr('minority')),
    ('majority', self.tr('majority')),
    ('q1', self.tr('q1')),
    ('q3', self.tr('q3')),
    ('iqr', self.tr('iqr')),
    ('empty', self.tr('empty')),
    ('filled', self.tr('filled')),
    ('min_length', self.tr('min_length')),
    ('max_length', self.tr('max_length')),
    ('mean_length', self.tr('mean_length'))]
```

So it's 0 - 18